# How to add a value to a column, according to a key in R

Tags: r

- a data of annual precipitation of each year in a data frame
- a data table, where are is the information of year

I need to add the information of the annual precipitation to the data table according to the year key.

```
data_table <- data.frame("dat" = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012))

prec_data <- data.frame("variable" = c(2010, 2011, 2012),
                "value" = c(500, 435, 451))

data_table$prec <- ??
```

Thank you for your attention and answers.

Comment: `merge(data_table, prec_data, by.x = 'dat', by.y = 'variable')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 merge(data_table, prec_data, by.x="dat", by.y="variable")
```